# Vite v5 build preview: This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite

I am building a React project to be published as an NPM package.

I've set up a React app via `npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template react`.

Here are the module settings and Vite script commands in `package.json`:

```
"name": "my-app",
"type": "module",
"files": [
  "dist"
],
"main": "./dist/my-app.umd.cjs",
"module": "./dist/my-app.js",
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "import": "./dist/my-app.js",
    "require": "./dist/my-app.umd.cjs"
  },
  "./dist/index.css": "./dist/style.css"
},
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

When I run `npm run dev`, dev server starts and the app works as expected.

When I run `npm run build` the app bundles the files in the `dist` folder as expected.

The problem is, once I tried to preview the `dist` build by running `npm run preview`, it gives me an error "This localhost page can’t be found".

Here are my settings in `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/main.jsx"),
      name: "my-app",
      fileName: "my-app",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And the `src/main.jsx` to render the app:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Since I'm using Vite [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build#library-mode), I am wondering if there are any other settings I must use for build preview to work?

I've also published the library to NPM registry to test it and I can install it via `npm i my-app` and the app works as expected, so the build must be right. Its just that I cant access the build preview in the development mode.

Thanks a lot in advance!